# NameNode not working

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to start hadoop modification called HaLoop but I have a problem in namenode. It doesn't start and give the following error

> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /app/haloop/tmp/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

The complete log is as follows:

> 2013-07-05 14:04:38,735 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
>   /************************************************************
>   STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode STARTUP_MSG:   host = elmorsy/127.0.1.1
>   STARTUP_MSG:   args = [] STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.2-dev
>   STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://haloop.googlecode.com/svn/trunk -r 408;
>   compiled by 'hduser' on Sat Jun 29 06:41:37 EET 2013
>   ************************************************************/ 2013-07-05 14:04:39,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.metrics.RpcMetrics:
>   Initializing RPC Metrics with hostName=NameNode, port=50010 2013-07-05
>   14:04:39,679 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
>   Namenode up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:50010 2013-07-05 14:04:39,701 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics
>   with processName=NameNode, sessionId=null 2013-07-05 14:04:39,711 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.metrics.NameNodeMetrics:
>   Initializing NameNodeMeterics using context
>   object:org.apache.hadoop.metrics.spi.NullContext 2013-07-05
>   14:04:40,360 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem:
>   fsOwner=hduser,hadoop 2013-07-05 14:04:40,360 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem:
>   supergroup=supergroup 2013-07-05 14:04:40,360 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem:
>   isPermissionEnabled=true 2013-07-05 14:04:40,388 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.metrics.FSNamesystemMetrics:
>   Initializing FSNamesystemMetrics using context
>   object:org.apache.hadoop.metrics.spi.NullContext 2013-07-05
>   14:04:40,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem:
>   Registered FSNamesystemStatusMBean 2013-07-05 14:04:40,531 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory
>   /app/haloop/tmp/dfs/name does not exist. 2013-07-05 14:04:40,547 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem
>   initialization failed.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException:
>   Directory /app/haloop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state:
>   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:290)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:87)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:311)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.(FSNamesystem.java:292)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:201)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:279)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:956)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:965)
>   2013-07-05 14:04:40,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping
>   server on 50010 2013-07-05 14:04:40,564 ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException:
>   Directory /app/haloop/tmp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state:
>   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible. at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:290)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:87)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:311)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.(FSNamesystem.java:292)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:201)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.(NameNode.java:279)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:956)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:965)
>
> 2013-07-05 14:04:40,572 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
>   /************************************************************
>   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at elmorsy/127.0.1.1
>   ************************************************************/

I tried to reformat NameNode but It didn't solve the problem.

Any help?

Comment: What are your hadoop.tmp.dir, dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir ? Those should be found in conf/hdfs-site.xml ?

Comment: If you haven't specified the later two then they are created under hadoop.tmp.dir which is generally in OS's /tmp file system. /tmp filesystem is occasionally cleaned by the OS corrupting the hadoop meta data. Try changing the dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir under your home or somewhere it'll persist. Then format the hadoop FS to do a fresh start.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the appropriate user and the directory has proper permissions. Use these commands to change the user and permissions of the directory, in case you need it :

```
sudo chown -R haloop_user:haloop_user_group /app/haloop/tmp/name
sudo chmod -R 755 /app/haloop/tmp/name
```

HTH

Comment: Hmmm..was the format successful?Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: yes format was successful and this is the only exception I get in the log

Comment: I added it in the question

Comment: Have you configured it from root?

Comment: No I have a hadoop user (hduser) which is used with it.

Comment: What was the problem with re-format? Delete the directory, format NN and let the directory get created on its own.

Comment: Also make sure that the value of "dfs.name.dir" is proper(doesn't have any space or somethin).

Comment: Your directory is haloop or hadoop (¿mistake configuration?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tariq's answer, and i solved it.
In addition, you should also chown and chmod the whole hadoop execution folder:

```
sudo chown -R hadoop_user:haloop_user_group /usr/local/hadoop
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop
```